# How much foreign currency gets injected into the British economy every year because of tax havens?

Tags: united-kingdom

[Britan's overseas territories combined are the largest tax havens in the world.](https://www.cityam.com/revealed-uk-and-british-overseas-territories-top-every-other-offshore-tax-haven-in-the-world-at-64-5bn-per-year/)

How much undocumented money from abroad gets injected into the documented British economy every year from its tax havens?

How else is the UK profiting from these tax havens?

Comment: This is going to be almost impossible to answer as most of that money is private and not known to the public.